# What does the notation P < NP exactly mean?

Tags: computational-complexity

Over the last days I stepped two times over the
notation P < NP, but I am not sure what it exactly means.
I first saw it here:

**P < NP In Our Stockings?**
https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2020/12/24/p-np-in-our-stockings/

And now here:

**Toward Combinatorial Proof of P < NP Basic Approach (119-128)**
https://www.cs.swansea.ac.uk/reports/yr2006/CSR7-2006.pdf

The abstract of the later paper says: "We present a plausibe
“school-algebraic” condition C0 that infers, in Peano Arithmetic,
the negative solution (abbr.: P < NP) to the familiar
open problem P =? NP."

Is P < NP a stronger statement than P ≠ NP? And infering P < NP
means here from PA+C0, and because C0 is doubtful, its not
really a proof of P ≠ NP?

Comment: You might try asking this question in cstheory.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $<$ sign here means "strict containment"; since we know that $P$ is contained in $NP$ it's equivalent to saying that $P \neq NP$.

> And infering P < NP means here from PA+C0, and because C0 is doubtful, its not really a proof of P ≠ NP?

Yes. It's not stated as clearly as it could be, but $C_0$ is an unproven conjecture.